# How to split Log files based on package name with few shared Java files as well?

Tags: java, logging, log4j

Background : I have developed a Java EE web application for **Requirement A** under **com.abc.A base package** *(A.java,B.java,C.java...100 of files)*, later client wanted to develop another **Requirement B** which is pretty much same with **Requirement A** so, i decided to develop **Requirement B** in same web application but in different base **package com.abc.B***(A.java,C.java...100 of files)*. Few java files are shared for both packages.

Question : I am using Log4J for logging, right now for entire project i have one log file. I want two separate log files based on base packages and also want to log the shared files even if its in different package

**File1 >> LogFileForA.txt**

**File2 >> LogFileForB.txt**

I can easily split log files based on package names but How can i split log files to log the shared Java files as well?

Answer (score 1):

I applied totally different approach to handle the share files in logging. This solution perfectly worked for me. Thanks to my Technical Key Lead(Ross Hardy) who put me on right track to get this done. 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

So you can basically define different appender in you log4j.xml . This will make sure that **com.abc.A** is written to **AFileAppender** and **com.abc.B** to **BFileAppender**

```
log4j.category.com.abc.A = INFO, AFileAppender
log4j.category.com.abc.B = INFO, BFileAppender
log4j.rootLogger = INFO, defaultAppender
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing but this solution ll not work of package A is sharing classes with B and B is sharing with. I have got working solution let me share in my answer